# Reactive Streams support for Room

Tags: android, android-sqlite, rx-java2, android-room, android-architecture-components

Subscriber doesn't receive any data from Flowable. Neither onNext() nor onError() are called. But when org.reactivestreams.Subscriber was replaced by io.reactivex.functions.Consumer it 
works perfect.

```
repository.getAgentInfo()
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new org.reactivestreams.Subscriber<AgentInfo>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
    Log.d("onSubscribe()", s.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(AgentInfo agentInfo) {
    Log.d("onNext()", agentInfo.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
    Log.d("onError()", t.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
    Log.d("onComplete()", "");
    }
});

@Dao
public interface FeedbackDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM PartnerInfoEntity LIMIT 1")
Flowable<AgentInfoInfoEntity> getAgentInfo();

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void inserntAgentInfo(AgentInfoInfoEntity agentInfoEntity);
```

}

Please explain to me why it does not work with subscriber

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109409709